# Index `coin` was not found on table `test.users`

Tags: javascript, node.js, rethinkdb

I'm using RethinkDB and i'm making a 'leaderboard' function. I keep getting that error every time i run the commands.

```
`Index `coin` was not found on table `test.users` in:
r.table("users").orderBy({
    index: r.desc("coin")

}).limit(10)
```

Before you say do i have 'coin' inserted, yes i do have it inserted

Comment: please add a sample of the input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an index on the "coin" field

```
r.table("users").indexCreate("coin")
```

Or use your orderby without index:

```
r.table("users").orderBy(r.desc("coin"))...
```

Answer (score 0):

The indexCreate method is an async method.
When inserting a new index, you need to verify its insertion by calling:

```
print(r.table(tablename).indexWait(sameIndexName))
```

That method acts like a 'yield' command that makes the DB stop whatever it's doing and creates that index for you. the result printed will include a property named ready. if it's 'true' you can start using the index in your queries.
You can read about it here: [Index Wait RethinkDB Documentation](https://www.rethinkdb.com/api/javascript/index_wait/).

Comment: I'm using NodeJS not Python. But, it already has been fixed and its working! I appreciate you trying to help me. :)